# E: Unable to locate package postgresql-server-dev-10 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, docker, postgresql, django, docker-compose

I am writing a Django app with postgresql, using Docker. However, for some reason building returns the error `"E: Unable to locate package postgresql-server-dev-10 The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-10 gcc python3-dev musl-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100`.

I tried changing it to `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client`, I tried also installing python, but nothing seems to work. Running `sudo apt install postgresql-server-dev-10` in my terminal works (I already had it installed), but when building it fails (`docker-compose build`).

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3.8

# set work directory
WORKDIR /weather_api

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-10 gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml is:

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/weather_api/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
  db:
    image: postgres:10.19
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=lavinia
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=#123$$
      - POSTGRES_DB=weatherdb

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

and requirements.txt

```
Django==3.2.9
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
```

If anyone could help me I would be so, so grateful. I really couldn't find anything helpful online and I am a beginner. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `python:3.8` image is based on Debian 11, so the package you need is [`postgresql-server-dev-13`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/postgresql-server-dev-13).

It would be simpler to install [`postgresql-server-dev-all`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/postgresql-server-dev-all), it will pull in the right version for you:

```
FROM python:3.8

# set work directory
WORKDIR /weather_api

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-server-dev-all gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . .
```